# How can i increase speed of for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to read the value of pixcels in  image result to compare this value with some 
I use to for loop

```
function GrdImg= GrdLbp(VarImg,mapping,LbpImg)
tic
p=mapping.samples;
[Ysize,Xsize]=size(result);
GImg=zeros(Ysize,Xsize);
temp=[];
cnt=1;
for n=0:p-1
    temp(cnt)=2^n;
    temp(cnt+1)=(2^p)-1-(2^n);
    cnt=cnt+2;
end
for i=1:Ysize
    i
        for j=1:Xsize
                if isempty(find(result(i,j)==temp(:,:)))==1
                  GImg(i,j)=sqrtm(Vresult(i,j));
                end


            end
        end
```

but it works too slow, Could you help me what can I use instead of for loop?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you trying to do with each of the pixels, that will make a difference in possible answers

Comment: you don't need to use the first 'for'. Maybe you don't need the second too but I didn't try.

Comment: where is the comparison part? The answer depends to that.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't really give enough information to answer your question - since, as was stated in the comments, you aren't doing anything with the values in the loop right now. So let me give you a few ideas:

1) To compare all the pixels with a fixed value, and return the index of all pixels greater than 90% of the maximum:

```
threshold = 0.9 * max(myImage(:));
prettyBigPixels = find(myImage > threshold);
```

2) To set all pixels < 5% of max to zero:

```
threshold = 0.05 * max(myImage(:));
myImage(myImage < threshold) = 0;
```

In the first case, the `find` command returns all the indices (note - you can access a 2D matrix of MxN with a single index that goes from 1 to M*N). You can use `ind2sub` to convert to the individual `i, j` coefficients if you want to.

In the second case, putting `(myImage < threshold)` as the index of the matrix is called *logical indexing* - it is very fast, and will access only those elements that meet the criterion.

If you let us know what you're actually doing with the values found we can speed things up more; because right now, the net result of your code is that when the loop is finished, your value `Temp` is equal to the last element - and since you did nothing in the loop we can rewrite the whole thing as

```
Temp = pixel(end);
```

**EDIT** Now that you show what you are doing in your inner loop, we can optimize more.  Behzad already showed how to speed up the computation of the vector `temp` - nothing to add there, it's the right way to do it.  As for the two nested loops, which are likely the place where most time is spent, you can find all the pixels you are interested in with a single line:

```
pixelsOfInterest = find(~ismember(result(:), temp(:)));
```

This will find the index of pixels in `result` that do not occur in `temp`. You can then do

```
GImg(pixelsOfInterest) = sqrt(result(pixelsOfInterest));
```

These two lines together should replace the functionality of everything in your code from `for i=1:Ysize` to the last `end`. Note - your variables seem to be uninitialized, and change names - sometimes it's `result`, sometimes it's `Vresult`. I am not trying to debug that; just giving you a fast implementation of your inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I completed my code, Could you help me again by this code?

Comment: There are a number of errors with your current code - `result` is not defined, other variables change names, there is a single `i` on a line by itself, indentation is messed up... I may have time to look at this later today - maybe you can fix it in the meantime?

Comment: I have updated my code with a couple of lines that replace your two `for` loops. I think I interpreted the logic correctly; if I didn't it should be easy to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your image is grayscle or monocolor , because `Temp=pixel(i,j)` gives a number not 3-numbers by the way.

Your question has not more explanation so I think in three type of numbers that you are comparison with.

1. compare with a constant number
2. compare with a series of numbers
3. compare with a two dimensional matrix of numbers

If first or third one is your need, solution is very easy (absolutely in third one, size of matrix must be equal to `pixel` size)

- Comparison with a number (`c` is number or two-dimensional array)

  ```
  comp=pixel - c;
  ```

  But if second one is your need, you can first reshape `pixel` to one-dimensional matrix then compare it with the series of number `s` (absolutely length of this serie must be equal to product of `pixel` rows number and columns number; you can re-reshape `pixel` matrix after comparison to primary two dimensional matrix.
- Comparison with a number serie `s`

  ```
  pixel_temp = reshape(pixel,1,[]);
  comp = pixel_temp - s;
  pixel_compared = reshape(pixel_temp,size(pixel,1),size(pixel,2));  % to re-reshape to primary size
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I want to compare with a series of numbers, but the length of this series isn't equal to product of pixel rows number and column number. I complete code in my question,Could you help me how can I do this?

Comment: I wrote next answer based on your new edition. It may helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of question completely edited I answer new rather than edit my former answer, by the way.

You can improve your code in some ways:
 1. instead of :

```
    for n=0:p-1
        temp(cnt)=2^n;
        temp(cnt+1)=(2^p)-1-(2^n);
        cnt=cnt+2;
    end
```

use this one:

```
    temp=zeros(1,2*p);
    n=0:p-1;
    temp(1:2:2*p)=2.^n; %//for odd elements 
    temp(2:2:2*p)=2^p-1-2.^n; %//for even elements (i supposed p>1)
```

2.when code is ready for calculating and not for debugging or other times, NEVER make some variables to print on screen because it makes too long time (in cpu cycles) to run. In your code there are some variables like `i` that prints on screen. remove them or end up them by `;`.

3.You can use `temp(:)` in last rows because `temp` is one-dimensional

4.Different functions are for different types of variables. in this code you can use `sqrt()` instead of `sqrtm()`. it may be slightly faster.

5. The big problem in this code is in your last comparison, if non elemnt of `temp` matrix is not equal with `result` specific element then do something! its hard to make this part improved unless knowing the real aim of the code! you may be solve the problem in other algorithm that has completely different code. But if there is no way, so use it in this way (nested loops) 
Good Luck!